# Is there a way to measure the viability of an experiment?

Tags: dataset, random-variable, statistical-power, uncertainty

Is there a way to calculate a number that evaluates the viability of an experiment? By that I mean the probability that the observed probability is just chance.

I read about the $p$ value, but it doesn't seem to be that, as it doesn't take at all into account the number of experiments.

Let's say I have an experience that I know should produce precisely a certain result, and that my experience proves it wrong. How many "tries" should I have done to consider my experience valid, and is there a measure for that?

Edit for a bit of clarification:

My experiment consists of taking a (computer generated) random integer number between 1 and 4 - assuming it distributing the numbers evenly.
Then, people are placed in front of four cards, representing one of these numbers, and have to choose one of them. Once chosed, the computer generates a number and if it as the same it is a success, otherwise a fail.

So the expected result is a 25% success rate. What I am wondering is if there exist a standard measurement for the fiability of an experiment, depending on the number of tests executed, so that if for example I see a 30% success rate I can assume that people are actually right 5% more than pure random luck

Comment: The statement in your second sentence sounds exactly like a p-values. A correctly calculated p-value does take into account the number of experiments, but the question in your last sentence is apparently about something other than what a p-value measures; you'd have to specify a criterion for 'valid'. Please try to figure out more clearly what you want to ask.

Comment: I added the power and power-analysis tags because I suspect that's what you're looking for. You may want to remove them if not.

Comment: Yes sorry I don't know much about statistics. I just read an article about the p value and it didn't seem to take into account the size of the data set but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does take the size of the dataset into account, at least in as much as you've used that dataset. It can be tricky to make sure you're incorporating what you need to into your significance test to get the right $p$.

Answer (score 1):

"An experience that I know should produce precisely a certain result" sounds like knowledge about the [effect size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) (or "strength"; see also [effect-size](/questions/tagged/effect-size) here on CV) of the cause-effect relationship. If you want to collect evidence that might falsify the [null hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) (see also [hypothesis-testing](/questions/tagged/hypothesis-testing)), according to which:

$H_0:$ effect size of cause-effect relationship $=0$ (i.e., no cause-effect relationship)

And you want to know how much data (i.e., how many observations) you'd need to collect to stand a fair chance of rejecting the null hypothesis, your question concerns [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) (see also the tags I added to your question), so you should look into performing a power analysis that's right for your purposes (which you may want to specify, if you have any in mind). If you know what the strength of the relationship (effect size) should be in the [population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_population), you can figure out how many observations you'd need to collect to falsify the null hypothesis, or to fit [confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) (see also [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval)) to your effect size estimate that don't include zero.

If you have higher requirements for the validity of your effect size estimate than that it be on the right side of zero (e.g., a negative [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) for an [inversely proportional relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_proportionality)), you may want to narrow your confidence intervals further than that, or increase your confidence level. These are slightly distinct (but directly related) issues:

- How wide is the margin of error (confidence interval, basically) around your estimate?
- How sure are you that your margins of error include the real [parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter)?

These are issues for you to decide as aspects of your statistical goal before you start collecting data, or at least before you stop collecting and before you start analyzing it, if you're genuinely concerned about interpreting your $p$ value in terms of an [$\alpha$ (Type I / false alarm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) error rate that you want to accept in advance for rejecting a null hypothesis (see [Wagenmakers, 2007](http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2007/pValueProblems.pdf)). If you just have some sense of how narrow you want your margin of error around your estimate to be, or how confident you want to be that your margin of error will end up overlapping with the real parameter, you can use power analysis to figure out how much data you need to collect to reach those goals, and you don't necessarily have to do this before analyzing your data. You may also want to read Geoff Cumming's spot in the APA Education Directorate: http://www.apa.org/education/ce/confidence-intervals.pdf‎.

And then there are [Bayesian methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_statistics) (see also [bayesian](/questions/tagged/bayesian), among other tags here on CV)...I'll let someone else cover those if they care to. (+1 for anyone who does from this guy right here!)

**Reference**

Wagenmakers, E. J. (2007). A practical solution to the pervasive problems of $p$ values. *Psychonomic Bulletin & Review, 14*(5), 779–804.